# UIView frame resets when moved in UIViewControllerContextTransitioning animateTransition:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a square in the middle of a view controller. I want to animate it and move it to the new view controller. However, it resets to (0,0) when I do that. Any suggestions?

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    //pointers to VCs
    PresentingViewController *fromVC = (PresentingViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    PresentedViewController *toVC = (PresentedViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    //add to view
    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    //make to view transparent
    UIColor *oldColor = toVC.view.backgroundColor;
    toVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //move square to new VC
    CGRect oldFrame = fromVC.square.frame;
    [toVC.view addSubview:fromVC.square];
    fromVC.square.frame = oldFrame; //view appears at 0,0 instead of the center. why???

    //animate expand and color change
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromVC.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
        toVC.view.backgroundColor = oldColor;
        fromVC.square.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(fromVC.square.transform, 1.5, 1.5);


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];

        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Do it still appear at (0,0) with this line `fromVC.square.frame = oldFrame` of code? Or is it that you notice the issue and added this line of code to move it to the centre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that this subview likely has constraints defined on it (either those you explicitly defined or those automatically added by Interface Builder), and when you move it to the destination view controller's view, it can't find the constraints, so the `frame` is ambiguously defined by auto layout.

You can either add constraints for the location of this subview in its new home, or you can set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `TRUE`, and it will define `constraints` from the `frame` and `autoresizingMask` to keep the view in the new location.

Answer (score 2):

It's very frustrating fighting auto layout in a custom transition animation. My advice is to not animate changes to the frame of a subview, but instead animate the subview's transform changing it to a translation transform. For example, use something like the following in the animation block:

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -40)
```

Then, in the completion block, if you need to set the subview's location back you can use the identity transform.

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

This approach works very nicely because it doesn't change the subview's frame which could cause auto layout to set it back.

Comment: I agree. Transforms all the way and save yourself some pain.